# Is it possible to access the current RenderTreeBuilder in a Blazor Razor file, or make a Component that doesn't change @key scope?

Tags: blazor

I'd like to write an EditorFor extension for Blazor, so in a .razor file you could do this

```
@Editor.For(Model.Address);
```

The problem is that I shouldn't new-up a component instance of a component in that code, but use `RenderTreeBuilder.OpenComponent<TComponent>`. But I can't see a way of getting hold of the current `RenderTreeBuilder` from inside a .razor file.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I could try?

I don't want to make this an `<EditorFor>` Component because that would change the scope of `@key` and would sometimes result in large render tree diffs when updating the DOM - unless there is a way to use `OpenComponent<T>` without changing the `@key` scope?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base class that you can inherit any Razor "Component" from. It will compile and produce a class object.  It's not a component because it doesn't implement `IComponent`,  but it opens up putting Razor defined markup in libraries without the `ComponentBase` burden.

```cs
public abstract class RazorBase
{
    protected abstract void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder);

    public RenderFragment Content => (builder) => BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

Here's a Razor file that demonstrates various methods pod building render fragments.  I've added a couple of *Editor* examples.

```cs
@using System.Globalization;
@inherits RazorBase

<h3>MyEditor</h3>

@code {

    // example mixing markup and c# method 
    public static RenderFragment Hello(string? name) => (__builder) =>
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@($"Hello {name}")</div>
    };

    public static RenderFragment GetMyTextEditor(object sender , string? value, Action<string?> valueSetter) => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(12, "input");
        builder.AddAttribute(13, "type", "text");
        builder.AddAttribute(14, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(15, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(value));
        builder.AddAttribute(21, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(sender, (e) => valueSetter.Invoke(e.Value?.ToString())));
        builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

    public static RenderFragment GetMyNumberEditor(object sender, int value, Action<int> valueSetter) => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(12, "input");
        builder.AddAttribute(13, "type", "number");
        builder.AddAttribute(14, "class", "form-control");
        builder.AddAttribute(15, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(value));
        builder.AddAttribute(21, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(sender, (e) => valueSetter.Invoke(ConvertToInt(e.Value?.ToString()))));
        builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
        builder.CloseElement();
    };

    private static int ConvertToInt(string? value)
    {
        BindConverter.TryConvertTo<int>(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here's a demo Index page.  I can't see a way to just pass in the value into the `RenderFragment` without having to implkment a callback.  Almost all edit fields are primitive value types.  Anyone any ideas?

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    @((new MyEditor()).Content)
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    @MyEditor.Hello("Blazor")
</div>

<div class="col">
    <label>Name</label>
    @MyEditor.GetMyTextEditor(this, myModel.Name, (returnValue) => myModel.Name = returnValue)
</div>
<div class="col">
    <label>Value</label>
    @MyEditor.GetMyNumberEditor(this, myModel.Value, (returnValue) => myModel.Value = returnValue)
</div>

<hr />

<div class="alert alert-info mt-4">
    <div class="">
        Name : @myModel.Name
    </div>
    <div class="">
        Value : @myModel.Value
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private String? value;
    private MyModel myModel = new();

    public class MyModel
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Large render tree diffs* I call *Render Cascades* or *Colateral Renders* (after colateral damage).  Lots of CPU activity achieving nothing!  I've moved to taking much tighter control of the render process: fix the problem, "Don't throw out the baby with the bathwater"!

Answer (score 1):

Using Extension methods you can achieve something similar to your request
(I have "borrowed" the text editor code from "Shaun Curtis" answer to keep things similar)

With these extensions in place, you can do this from any component/razor file (where `FirstNameChanged` is a `ChangeEventArgs` handler) and it will use the current `RenderTreeBuilder`

```cs
@this.EditorFor(Model.FirstName,FirstNameChanged)
```

`Extensions.cs`

```cs
public static class ComponentExtensions
{
  public static RenderFragment EditorFor(
    this IComponent component,
    string Item,
    Func<ChangeEventArgs, Task> ItemChanged,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("Item")] string Label = "")
    => (RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => builder.RenderTextEditor(Label, Item, EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(component, ItemChanged));
  
  public static RenderFragment EditorFor(
    this IComponent component,
    string Item,
    Func<Task> ItemChanged,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("Item")] string Label = "")
    => (RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => builder.RenderTextEditor(Label, Item, EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(component, ItemChanged));
  
  public static RenderFragment EditorFor(
    this IComponent component,
    string Item,
    Action<ChangeEventArgs> ItemChanged,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("Item")] string Label = "")
    => (RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => builder.RenderTextEditor(Label, Item, EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(component, ItemChanged));
  
  public static RenderFragment EditorFor(
    this IComponent component,
    string Item,
    Action ItemChanged,
    [CallerArgumentExpression("Item")] string Label = "")
    => (RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => builder.RenderTextEditor(Label, Item, EventCallback.Factory.Create<ChangeEventArgs>(component, ItemChanged));
  
  public static void RenderTextEditor(
    this RenderTreeBuilder builder,
        string Label,
        string Item,
        EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> ItemChanged)
  {
    //TODO: don't calculate these - this was just POC
    var id = Label;
    var labelText = Label.Split('.').LastOrDefault();
    builder.OpenElement(1, "label");
    builder.AddAttribute(2, "for", id);
    builder.AddContent(3, labelText);
    builder.CloseElement();
    builder.OpenElement(4, "input");
    builder.AddAttribute(5, "id", id);
    builder.AddAttribute(6, "type", "text");
    builder.AddAttribute(7, "class", "form-control");
    builder.AddAttribute(8, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(Item));
    builder.AddAttribute(9, "onchange", ItemChanged);
    builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
    builder.CloseElement();
  }
}
```